# How to move a page horizontally when scrolling the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello guys can you help me with my problem?
I have a list of maps in my page. In every page there is 40 different maps. So in order to view the last map I need to hold down the mouse and scroll horizontally to the right to view this. But how can I do this using scrolling down/up of the mouse?

I am a beginner in jquery/javascript that's why I don't have an idea how to do this.

Here's my sample html code.

```
<div id="horizontal">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://localhost/img1.jpg" height="300" widt="300" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
...
var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

$(window).scroll(function () {
     //how to detect the scrolling of the mouse?
});
```

Ont more question. Where should I place the div tag horizontal? Is it in the  tag? or  tag? Ok that's all. Here's my sample fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/A3UHf/

Comment: I saw that, but the link for javascript file is no longer available.

Comment: I saw the code but how can I include the javascript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Brandon Aaron's jquery plugin to trigger horizontal scrolling with mousewheel

**http://jsfiddle.net/A3UHf/5/**

```
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [mousewheel plugin](http://brandon.aaron.sh/code/mousewheel/docs). scrolling horizontally with the mousewheel should then work with this code:

```
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: if this was posted an hour ago and the other answer was posted 15 min ago, and they're the same answer.... why was the other one accepted??

Comment: yes, I am aksing myself the same thing. Mine being accepted would mean I would get the right to comment on other questions finally

Comment: I helped you out a little...